# Convert string to Key Value Pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to build some key value pair in my application and read it in jQuery.Please consider this sample code:

```
string s = "'{\"96\": \"0\",";
s += "\"97\": \"1\"}'";
HiddenField1.Value = s;
```

and read it in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        var Dictionary = $('#HiddenField1').val();

        $.each(Dictionary , function (key, value) {
            alert(key + ': ' + value);               
        });
    });
```

the problem is I want to convert this string to Key Value pairs. I couldn't use `jQuery.parseJSON` and I got `Invalid character`.

How I can do this?

Comment: So...remove the invalid characters (the `'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave out the `'`, the string is valid JSON otherwise:

```js
var s = "{\"96\": \"0\",";
s += "\"97\": \"1\"}";
var Dictionary = JSON.parse(s);
$.each(Dictionary, function(key, value) {
  snippet.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
var s = '{\"96\": \"0\",';
s += '\"97\": \"1\"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(s));
```

> Object {96: "0", 97: "1"}

Comment: Remove the \ in front of the double quotes

Comment: Why? He had that, I reproduced his case.

Comment: @Michelem: His string was quoted with `"`, so he *had* to escape them. You quoted yours with `'`, so you don't. They're harmless, though.